# Checking a values is null or not inside where condition MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have a advanced search form which passes **many variables** to another page `next.php`.

My question is I want to check the variable is null or not inside query .

Can i use like this or is there any function like this??

```
$price=$_GET['price'];
$query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE (if price!='' { $price; } )";
```

Simply i want is if `$price` is null , i do not want check in where condition because it affects results.

How to do this guys??

Give me a solution

Thankss

Comment: elaborate what result you need if price is null and what if not null.

Comment: Cool....@newbie...r u asking help or assigning task...

Answer (score 0):

Just check **BEFORE** querying anything. Why would you waste time in generating query if you have nothing to generate with?

```
$price=$_GET['price'];
if($price !== NULL) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help...this method gives many queries...because i am passing many variables , so want to check in a single query.

Comment: Do I understand this correct? You create some variables from global `$_GET` without even checking if key exists and then want to pass only those variables to query which exist?

Comment: No, in search form we can select drop down with min price, max price ,brand,category,and so on... etc. if we click brand then only selected brand should display...as there are many variables i need a single query to check is null, else somany checks needed..